# How to get values of a ListView items when clicking on the listview item's button

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an activity called `ListOfPetsActivity.java` which is displaying a ListView of Pet object.
**Pet.java** looks like this

```
    public class Pet {
    
        private int petId;
        private String petName;
        private int age;
        //getters, setters and constructors
    }
```

I am displaying the pet objects in the ListView with a custom adapter which currently only displays the pet's name and has a button called `requestAcceptButton`.

Here is the adapter

```
    public class RequesterAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Pet> {
    
        private List<Pet> requestersList;
        private Context context;
    
        public RequesterAdapter(Context context, List<Pet> requestersList) {
            super(context, -1, requestersList);
            this.context = context;
            this.requestersList = requestersList;
        }
    
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View currentItemView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            if (currentItemView == null) {
                currentItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.requester_item, parent, false);
            }
    
            // get the position of the view from the ArrayAdapter
            Pet currentPetPosition = getItem(position);
    
            TextView requesterNameTextView = currentItemView.findViewById(R.id.requesterNameTextView);
            requesterNameTextView.setText(currentPetPosition.getPetName() + ", " +currentPetPosition.getAge());
    
            Button requestAcceptButton = currentItemView.findViewById(R.id.requestAcceptButton);
            
            return currentItemView;
        }
    
    }
```

Now, the current activity which shows the ListView of all the pets, `ListOfPetsActivity.java` shows the list of pets with their name and age and has a button next to it.
When I click on it, I want to get all values from the pet object from that ListView item and save it in variables of string and int type so that I can communicate with the database. The thing is, I need to do that in this activity and not in the adapter. So, how am I able to get all items from the ListView item?

I am setting up the ListView and its adapter like this in the `ListOfPetsActivity`.

```
    RequesterAdapter requesterAdapter = new RequesterAdapter(ListOfPetsActivity.this, friendRequesterPetsList);
    requesterListView.setAdapter(requesterAdapter);
```

Comment: `private List<Pet> requestersList;` Make that public. Grab the Pet list with `requestAdapter.requestList`. Or yet simpler: just use `friendRequesterPetsList`.

Answer (score 0):

Step1:
Create one interface

```
interface PetClickListener {
      fun onPetSelected(petAge: Int)
}
```

Step2: Implement interface in your Activity:

```
ListOfPetsActivity implement PetClickListener {
{
  override onPetSelected(petAge: Int) {
       // here you will get pet Age of selected Pet in the list
  }
}
```

Step3: update your adapter constructor:

```
RequesterAdapter requesterAdapter = new RequesterAdapter(ListOfPetsActivity.this, friendRequesterPetsList, this);
```

Step4: Create one global variable in adapter:

```
private PetClickListener petClickListener;
```

Step5: Initialise it in constructor:

```
public RequesterAdapter(Context context, List<Pet> requestersList, PetClickListener listener) {
        super(context, -1, requestersList);
        this.context = context;
        this.requestersList = requestersList;
        petClickListener = listener;
    }
```

Step6: use this petClickListener when you click on button

```
requestAcceptButton.setOnClickListener {
    petClickListener(currentPetPosition.getAge())
}
```

This way you will get a callback in your activity with pet age.
Note: I have used Kotlin and java here. But this will give you an idea to solve your issue.

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Hello, this is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `interface` for getting your `Pet` object in the activity.

Create an interface in your `RequesterAdapter` class

```
  public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(Pet pet);
  }
```

Change `RequestAdapter` constructor to accept `ItemClickListener` and assign it to `itemClickListener` object.

```
private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
public RequesterAdapter(Context context, List<Pet> requestersList, ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
            super(context, -1, requestersList);
            this.context = context;
            this.requestersList = requestersList;
            this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
        }
```

Implement this interface in `MainActivity` and override `onItemClick`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RequesterAdapter.ItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(Pet pet) {
        // execute your database operations
    }
}
```

Trigger `onItemClick` method, from `requestAcceptButton` `clickListener`

```
requestAcceptButton.setOnClickListener(view -> itemClickListener.onItemClick(currentPetPosition));
```